# Error while using IntelliJ and JavaFX 11 with jdk 11

Tags: intellij-idea, javafx

I have created JavaFX application with SceneBuilder on IntelliJ.
JavaFX is installed successfully as there in no JavaFX related error in the code.

While setting VM option in the configuration of the program, the program is giving me below error:

**Error:**

```
Could not find or load main class Files\Java\openjfx-15-ea+4_windows-x64_bin-sdk\javafx-sdk-15\lib
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Files\Java\openjfx-15-ea+4_windows-x64_bin-sdk\javafx-sdk-15\lib
```

I am using VM option path as : --module-path

```
C:\Program Files\Java\openjfx-15-ea+4_windows-x64_bin-sdk\javafx-sdk-15\lib
--add-modules=javafx.controls,javafx.fxmlse
```

Can some one know how to resolve this issue?

Comment: in --module-path C:\Program Files\Java\openjfx-15-ea+4_windows-x64_bin-sdk\javafx-sdk-15\lib --add-modules=javafx.controls,javafx.fxmlse          the last module is javafx.fxml   not " javafx.fxmlse "   in  VM option

Comment: Hi it was typo.

Comment: Even with --module-path
C:\Program
Files\Java\openjfx-15-ea+4_windows-x64_bin-sdk\javafx-sdk-15\lib
--add-modules=javafx.controls,javafx.fxml,javafx.graphics,javafx.base 
this path its not working

Comment: there is another way to add javafx to your project https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WtOgoomDewo . this works for me